# When function triggers, inside for loop number return default value again

Tags: javascript

I have a function inside a for loop. it's like;

```
function a(){
   var i=0;
   var endNumber= data.number;
   for(;i=!endNumber;i++){
      //doing stuff
   }
}
```

So, I want when function calls "i" value gets end of "i" value again. Because `data.number` always changes.

Comment: Move `var i = 0;` outside the function.

Comment: Or return `i` and use it like this `var lastValueOfI = a();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
let data = { number: 5 };

function a() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    var endNumber = data.number;
    for (; i !== endNumber; i++) {
       console.log(i);
    }
    console.log('done');
  }
}

const func = a();

func();
data = { number: 10 };
func();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either declare `i` outside of the loop, so that it is independent of the function calls:

```
var i = 0;

funcion a() { /*...*/ }
```

Or return `i` from the function and pass it in the next time (might be a bit cleaner):

```
function a(i = 0) {
 while(i !== data.number) {
   //...
   i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

So one can do:

```
var prev = a();

a(prev);
```